# CBCentralManager restarts after connect

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-bluetooth

I'm having a problem on my MacBook Pro. I have a small utility program that I'm using to communicate with a BLE peripheral we are developing. It shares code base with an iOS application that works with no problem (regarding the BLE anyway…)

On my Mac however, and I believe this surfaced coincidentally with upgrading to macOS Sierra, the CBCentralManager restarts whenever I try to connect to my peripheral. The exact timings and sequencing are shown below. I looked through my VCS and found no changes since upgrading, and I'm sure this wasn't present before.
I've tested on my colleague's MacBook Pro, where it works. On mine, it fails every single time.

Anyone has any clue on why this is happening? Or if it is possible to see the causing on why the CBCentralManager is restarting?

```
2016-10-18 15:38:05.800350 [58103:17219669] Connecting to XXX.
2016-10-18 15:38:06.026459 [58103:17219669] Connected to XXX.
2016-10-18 15:38:06.027589 [58103:17219669] Discovered services for peripheral XXX
2016-10-18 15:38:06.027636 [58103:17219669] Found X service.
2016-10-18 15:38:06.199486 [58103:17219669] Discovered Y characterstic
2016-10-18 15:38:06.199671 [58103:17219669] Discovered Z characterstic
2016-10-18 15:38:06.221585 [58103:17219669] Central manager updated state: Resetting
2016-10-18 15:38:06.818771 [58103:17219669] Central manager updated state: Powered on
```

---

Edit: I have tried restarting the Mac and resetting the SMC, with no success. Other BLE stuff works (mouse, keyboard and headset), but the peripheral works with all other units as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error disappeared after a while, with no active action from my part. There were some updates from Apple since, so that might have affected it. Hence, the solution appears to be 'sit tight'.